# How can I get the WAV data from the whole song?

Tags: c++, fmod

I'm using FMOD (with C++ syntax, not C) and I'm having trouble getting the wave data of a whole sound file.

Channel::GetWave() only gets the wave data of the area on which it is currently playing.

The documentation says:

> Do not use this function to try and display the whole waveform of the
>   sound, as this is more of a 'snapshot'
>   of the current waveform at the time it
>   is called, and could return the same
>   data if it is called very quickly in
>   succession.
>
> See the DSP API to capture a continual stream of wave data as it
>   plays, or see Sound::lock /
>   Sound::unlock if you want to simply
>   display the waveform of a sound.

Unfortunately, the Sound::lock and unlock functions are pretty confusing,  at least to me.

Lock:

```
FMOD_RESULT Sound::lock(
  unsigned int  offset, 
  unsigned int  length, 
  void **  ptr1, 
  void **  ptr2, 
  unsigned int *  len1, 
  unsigned int *  len2
);
```

> offset
>
> Offset in bytes to the position you want to lock in the sample buffer.
>
> length
>
> Number of bytes you want to lock in the sample buffer.
>
> ptr1
>
> Address of a pointer that will point to the first part of the locked
>   data.
>
> ptr2
>
> Address of a pointer that will point to the second part of the locked
>   data. This will be null if the data
>   locked hasn't wrapped at the end of
>   the buffer.
>
> len1
>
> Length of data in bytes that was locked for ptr1
>
> len2
>
> Length of data in bytes that was locked for ptr2. This will be 0 if the
>   data locked hasn't wrapped at the end
>   of the buffer.

Unlock:

```
FMOD_RESULT Sound::unlock(
  void *  ptr1, 
  void *  ptr2, 
  unsigned int  len1, 
  unsigned int  len2
);
```

> ptr1
>
> Pointer to the 1st locked portion of sample data, from Sound::lock.
>
> ptr2
>
> Pointer to the 2nd locked portion of sample data, from Sound::lock.
>
> len1
>
> Length of data in bytes that was locked for ptr1
>
> len2
>
> Length of data in bytes that was locked for ptr2. This will be 0 if the data locked hasn't wrapped at the end of the buffer.

But as I said, my goal is to be able to get the wave data of the beginning of a song to the end.

Answer (score 2):

The way I read it, the last four parameters are *output parameters*. So you basically pass in 4 variables of the requested type and after the function has finished, these are populated with the data you need.

What you do is something along these lines:

```
void  *pointer1;
void  *pointer2;
unsigned int length1;
unsigned int length2;

// lock the buffer
mySound->lock(0, lengthOfYourSoundInBytes, &pointer1, &pointer2, &length1, &length2);

// when we're here, pointer1, pointer2, length1 and length2 will be populated.
// do something with the sound data found in pointer1.
// the sound data will have a length stored in length1

// unlock the buffer once you're done
mySound->unlock(pointer1, pointer2, length1, length2);
```

From my understanding you won't need `pointer2` and `length2` at all.
The only thing you'll have to figure out is the length of your sound data (see `lengthOfYourSoundInBytes` above). Once you locked the buffer, you'll get a pointer to the data and you can do whatever you want with it.